# How to add a component into a JComponent with absolute positioning?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, absolutelayout

Here is my current settings:

```
    private JComponent upperContent = new GeneralContent();
    private JComponent lowerContent = new GeneralContent();
    // GeneralContent extends JComponent

   jframe.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 0));
   upperContent.setLayout(null);
   lowerContent.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
   jframe.add(upperContent);
   jframe.add(lowerContent)
```

lowerContent's all component are displayed as expected while upperContent didn't display the component that i was added to it by using the following code:

```
JLabel label=new JLabel();
upperContent.add(label);
label.setLocation(15,15);
```

i also used label.repaint(); & upperContent.revalidate() neither worked

Comment: Use layouts (+layout padding and borders) to achieve the required effect.  The `null` layout will come back to bite you in the posterior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get absolute positioning with a null layout.  The bad news is that everything is totally up to you from then on.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html

Comment: using getPreferredSize() & setBounds() solved the problem, many thanks